# How to start using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use NumPy. Specifically, to run:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]]
ary1d = np.array(1st)
ary1d
array([[1, 2, 3,],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

However, I am not sure whether this is code that is meant to be typed into the command terminal or IDLE. I have Conda and Pip installed. I have consulted multiple online and text references, however they do not provide guidance on where and how to use NumPy. The materials assume that the reader knows these things and skip over it, so I am having trouble solving the problem. My question is how do I use NumPy to effectively run the function above.

Thanks in advance for your time and help! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try some googling before asking

Comment: If you have conda installed I think easiest way to start is to use Spyder. It is already installed in your computer. Find that in the application list and you can run those commands in an environment where numpy is installed.

Comment: SO is sometimes very un-welcoming to beginners and often scares them away @ArpitSolanki I understand the question isn't the best but still guiding the user is better then telling them to use google. He clearly made some effort and telling them to google just makes newbies less likely to use SO or even improve on how to ask questions.

Comment: Not likely to get a lot of love here with this kind of question, but if you have installed python with Anaconda then you probably have the spyder IDE as well.  Open your anaconda command prompt and type `spyder`.  This will give you an editor and ipython console that you can run your code in.  It's a good place to start, especially with numpy because the variable explorer is really useful.

Comment: Use the spyder ide instead of IDLE if you don't want to use a terminal...

Comment: You may have to install numpy. Installation of a conda package is described at: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html It's probably something like: `conda install numpy`

Comment: Thanks for the input- I appreciate the feedback on question format as well. My goal is to work hard to add value to the SO community.

Comment: you can type it into the interpreter. Check out ipython, it's a great interactive python interpreter https://ipython.org/install.html

Comment: @Mark your point is perfectly valid but you understand that answering this is too broad and mainly opinion based as you can also see in comments that everyone has different suggestions. I am just encouraging him to use google first.

Comment: @Arpit Solanki to be clear, I stated in the question that I had already consulted multiple online and text references. Google, was included within my online search. However, I could not solve my problem. If you have more specific advice on the types of questions I should post or how to post a question, then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, install NumPy:

`conda install numpy` or `pip install numpy` should work.

Afterwards, you can use it either in an interactive session (using the `python` command, `ipython`, or an IDE like Spyder) or by putting it in a standard python file and running it. I personally like to use iPython just for playing around with a package like this.

In the code snippet you posted in your question it looks like it has been run in an interactive python session, which can make it confusing what the input is and what the output is. Maybe this helps:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: lst = [[1, 2, 3],
   ...:        [4, 5, 6]]

In [3]: ary1d = np.array(list)

In [4]: ary1d
Out[4]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Specifically, that's what it looks like if I run the code in iPython. The last line starting with array() is just the interpreter printing out ary1d (since interactive interpreters print out the variable if you just input the variable itself). In a standard python file, the equivalent equivalent would be:

```
import numpy as np      # Import NumPy
lst = [[1, 2, 3],       # Nested list of values
       [4, 5, 6]]
ary1d = np.array(lst)   # This defines a 2D 3x2 array from the values
print(ary1d.__repr__()) # Print a string representation of the array. print(ary1d) also
                        # works but prints a slightly different format
```

I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: That helped! Thank you!